# How to make my Discord Bot to work simultaneously in different servers? (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have been trying to make a discord game bot with discord.py. Whenever I run the bot and start the game in one server, I cant be able to start another game in another server. The game gets mixed up. Also I want the bot to be able to handle two different users in the same server.
I will post the bot's code below. It is just a rough code and not well optimized. So please go easy on the code

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio

from time import sleep

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="&help"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if message.content.lower() == "&help":
        await message.channel.send(" Just a hand cricket bot :) \n&start - To start a match \nFollow along to complete the match \n(There will be glitches) ")
    
    if message.content.lower() == "&start":
        
        while True:
            
            try:
                
                await message.channel.send("Choose a number(1-10) and odd or even (For eg: 2 odd, 5 even) : ")
                msg1 = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30)
                
                if msg1.author == message.author:
                    ch = random.randint(1,10)
                    inp = msg1.content.split()
                    
                    start = True
                    
                    if int(inp[0]) <= 10 and int(inp[0]) > 0:
                        if inp[1].lower() == "even":
                            
                            if (ch + int(inp[0])) % 2 == 0:
                                await message.channel.send(f" I chose {ch} \nYou win")
                                start = False
                                break
                            
                            else:
                                await message.channel.send(f" I chose {ch} \nYou lose")
                                break
                        
                        else:
                            
                            if (ch + int(inp[0])) % 2 != 0:
                                await message.channel.send(f" I chose {ch} \nYou win")
                                start = False
                                break
                            
                            else:
                                await message.channel.send(f" I chose {ch} \nYou lose")
                                break
                    
                    else:
                        pass
                
                else:
                    pass
            
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.channel.send("You took too much time.")
                break
            
            except:
                await message.channel.send("Choose properly.")
        
        ch = random.choice(['Bat','Bowl'])
        await message.channel.send("Rules: Only 1-6 allowed. I will send msg after you send. If you want to quit send 0.")
        
        if start == True and ch.lower() == "bowl":
            await message.channel.send(f"I will {ch}. Send your msg for first ball")
            xyz = True
            score_h = 0
            score_b = 0
            
            while xyz:
                msg2 = await client.wait_for('message')
                
                if msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) == 0:
                    await message.channel.send("Bye")
                    xyz = False
                    break
                
                elif msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) < 7 and int(msg2.content) > 0:
                    choice = random.randint(1,6)
                    
                    if int(msg2.content) == choice:
                        await message.channel.send("Out!!!!!")
                        sleep(0.5)
                        await message.channel.send("I will bat now. Send your msg for first ball")
                        
                        while True:
                            msg3 = await client.wait_for('message')
                            
                            if msg3.author == message.author and int(msg3.content) == 0:
                                await message.channel.send("Bye")
                                xyz = False
                                break
                            
                            if msg3.author == message.author and int(msg3.content) < 7 and int(msg3.content) > 0:
                                choice1 = random.randint(1,6)
                                score_b += choice1
                                
                                if score_b > score_h:
                                    await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                    await message.channel.send(f"Win!! :) \nFinal Score: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot: {score_b} \nThanks for playing :)")
                                    xyz = False
                                    break
                                
                                elif (score_b - choice1) < score_h:
                                    
                                    if int(msg3.content) == choice1:
                                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                        await message.channel.send(f"Out :( \nFinal Score: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot: {score_b - choice1} \nThanks for playing :)")
                                        xyz = False
                                        break
                                    
                                    else:
                                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                                        sleep(0.5)
                            
                            elif msg3.author != message.author:
                                continue
                            
                            else:
                                if not msg3.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")
                    
                    else:
                        score_h += int(msg2.content)
                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg2.content}. I chose {choice}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                        sleep(0.5)
                
                elif msg2.author != message.author:
                    continue
                
                else:
                    if not msg2.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")   
        
        if start == True and ch.lower() == "bat":
            await message.channel.send(f"I will {ch}. Send your msg for first ball")
            score_h = 0
            score_b = 0
            xyz = True
            
            while xyz:
                msg2 = await client.wait_for('message')
                
                if msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) == 0:
                    await message.channel.send("Bye")
                    xyz = False
                    break
                
                elif msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) < 7 and int(msg2.content) > 0:
                    choice = random.randint(1,6)
                    
                    if int(msg2.content) == choice:
                        await message.channel.send("Out!!!!!")
                        sleep(0.5)
                        await message.channel.send("I will bowl now. Send your msg for first ball")
                        
                        while True:
                            msg3 = await client.wait_for('message')
                            
                            if msg3.author == message.author and int(msg3.content) == 0:
                                await message.channel.send("Bye")
                                xyz = False
                                break
                            
                            if msg3.author == message.author and int(msg3.content) < 7 and int(msg3.content) > 0:
                                choice1 = random.randint(1,6)
                                score_h += int(msg3.content)
                                
                                if score_b < score_h:
                                    await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                    await message.channel.send(f"Win!! :) \nFinal Score: \nBot: {score_b} \nHuman: {score_h}\nThanks for playing :)")
                                    xyz = False
                                    break
                                
                                elif score_b > (score_h - int(msg3.content)):
                                    
                                    if int(msg3.content) == choice1:
                                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                        await message.channel.send(f"Out :( \nFinal Score: \nBot: {score_b} \nHuman: {score_h - int(msg3.content)} \nThanks for playing :)")
                                        xyz = False
                                        break
                                    
                                    else:
                                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                                        sleep(0.5)
                            
                            elif msg3.author != message.author:
                                continue
                            
                            else:
                                if not msg3.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")
                    
                    else:
                        score_b += choice
                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg2.content}. I chose {choice}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                        sleep(0.5)
                
                elif msg2.author != message.author:
                    continue
                
                else:
                    if not msg2.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")
        
        elif start == False:
            await message.channel.send("1. Bat \n2. Bowl")
            cho = (await client.wait_for('message')).content
            
            if cho == "0":
                await message.channel.send("Bye")
            
            elif cho == "1":
                await message.channel.send(f"I will bowl. Send your msg for first ball")
                score_h = 0
                score_b = 0
                xyz = True
                
                while xyz:
                    msg2 = await client.wait_for('message')
                    
                    if msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) == 0:
                        await message.channel.send("Bye")
                        xyz = False
                        break
                    
                    elif msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) < 7 and int(msg2.content) > 0:
                        choice = random.randint(1,6)
                        
                        if int(msg2.content) == choice:
                            await message.channel.send("Out!!!!!")
                            sleep(0.5)
                            await message.channel.send("I will bat now. Send your msg for first ball")
                            
                            while True:
                                msg3 = await client.wait_for('message')
                                
                                if msg3.author == message.author and int(msg3.content) == 0:
                                    await message.channel.send("Bye")
                                    xyz = False
                                    break
                                
                                elif msg3.author == message.author and int(msg3.content) < 7 and int(msg3.content) > 0:
                                    choice1 = random.randint(1,6)
                                    score_b += choice1
                                    
                                    if score_b > score_h:
                                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                        await message.channel.send(f"Win!! :) \nFinal Score: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot:{score_b} \nThanks for playing :)")
                                        xyz = False
                                        break
                                    
                                    elif (score_b - choice1) < score_h:
                                        
                                        if int(msg3.content) == choice1:
                                            await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                            await message.channel.send(f"Out :(  \nFinal Score: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot:{(score_b - choice1)} \nThanks for playing :)")
                                            xyz = False
                                            break
                                        
                                        else:
                                            await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                                            sleep(0.5)
                                
                                elif msg3.author != message.author:
                                    continue
                                
                                else:
                                    if not msg3.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")
                        
                        else:
                            score_h += int(msg2.content)
                            await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg2.content}. I chose {choice}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                            sleep(0.5)
                    
                    elif msg2.author != message.author:
                        continue
                    
                    else:
                        if not msg2.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")
            
            elif cho == "2":
                await message.channel.send(f"I will bat. Send your msg for first ball")
                score_h = 0
                score_b = 0
                xyz = True
                
                while xyz:
                    msg2 = await client.wait_for('message')
                    
                    if msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) == 0:
                        await message.channel.send("Bye")
                        xyz = False
                        break
                    
                    elif msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) < 7 and int(msg2.content) > 0:
                        choice = random.randint(1,6)
                        
                        if int(msg2.content) == choice:
                            await message.channel.send("Out!!!!!")
                            sleep(0.5)
                            await message.channel.send("I will bowl now. Send your msg for first ball")
                            
                            while True:
                                msg3 = await client.wait_for('message')
                                
                                if msg2.author == message.author and int(msg2.content) == 0:
                                    await message.channel.send("Bye")
                                    xyz = False
                                    break
                                
                                if msg3.author == message.author and int(msg3.content) < 7 and int(msg3.content) > 0:
                                    choice1 = random.randint(1,6)
                                    score_h += int(msg3.content)
                                    
                                    if score_b < score_h:
                                        await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                        await message.channel.send(f"Win!! :) \nFinal Score: \nBot: {score_b} \nHuman: {score_h} \nThanks for playing :)")
                                        xyz = False
                                        break
                                    
                                    elif score_b > (score_h - int(msg3.content)):
                                        
                                        if int(msg3.content) == choice1:
                                            await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}.")
                                            await message.channel.send(f"Out :( \nFinal Score: \nBot: {score_b} \nHuman: {(score_h - int(msg3.content))} \nThanks for playing :)")
                                            xyz = False
                                            break
                                        
                                        else:
                                            await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg3.content}. I chose {choice1}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                                            sleep(0.5)
                                
                                elif msg3.author != message.author:
                                    continue
                                
                                else:
                                    if not msg3.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")
                        
                        else:
                            score_b += choice
                            await message.channel.send(f"You chose {msg2.content}. I chose {choice}. \nScore: \nHuman: {score_h} \nBot : {score_b}")
                            sleep(0.5)
                    
                    elif msg2.author != message.author:
                        continue
                    
                    else:
                        if not msg2.author.bot: await message.channel.send("Enter correct number")

client.run(r'token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see here, is that you are using `sleep()` from `time`, which is blocking. So instead of `sleep(0.5)` use `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)`. This should make your bot work in multiply servers.

Edit: Thanks to the clarification of the problem I figured out something different. With `check` in `client.wait_for`, you can filter which messages count for `wait_for`. So add this to the top of your on_message:

```py
def check(msg):
    return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
```

and in every `client.wait_for` add `check=check` as an argument like this for example:

```py
msg1 = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30, check=check)
```

Now the bot will simply ignore messages by other users or in other servers, and everything worked when I tested it.

References:

[client.wait_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: Thank you for the reply
But the bot is still treating inputs from different people at different servers as the same
What are the changes I should do to treat them differently?

Comment: I just edited the answer to use `client.wait_for`, and now it works! @UditKrishna